# How to pass a const void * to node.js?

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js

i'm extending the [libspotify](https://developer.spotify.com/docs/libspotify/12.1.45/) wrapper of [node-libspotify](https://github.com/swissmanu/node-libspotify) to support album cover images.
so far, i have the following, working c-binding code:

```
static Handle<Value> Album_Cover(const Arguments& args) {
    HandleScope scope;

    // test arguments sanity
    assert(args.Length() == 2);
    assert(args[0]->IsObject());  // sp_session
    assert(args[1]->IsObject());  // sp_album

    ObjectHandle<sp_session> *session = ObjectHandle<sp_session>::Unwrap(args[0]);
    ObjectHandle<sp_album> *album = ObjectHandle<sp_album>::Unwrap(args[1]);

    const byte *image_id = sp_album_cover(album->pointer, SP_IMAGE_SIZE_LARGE);
    size_t image_size;
    const void *image_data;

    if(image_id) {
        sp_image *image = sp_image_create(session->pointer, image_id);
        image_data = sp_image_data(image, &image_size);

        sp_image_release(image);
    }

    return scope.Close(image_data);
}
```

i struggle on the last line: how can i pass the raw image data over to node.js when running `scope.Close(...)`?

thanks for any suggestsions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap it in a [v8::Value](http://izs.me/v8-docs/classv8_1_1Value.html) as `v8::HandleScope::Close` expects a handle to one as an argument.

I guess `v8::String` should do it - [v8::String Class Reference](http://izs.me/v8-docs/classv8_1_1String.html#af0f9c44d85056bd575c01e8be7cc1b01)

```
scope.Close(String::New((const char*)image_data, image_size));
```

A `v8::Array` might be useful too - it all depends on how you are going to use the returned value afterwards.

I hope this helps.

Comment: awesome! i was not aware that i can create the v8::String and v8::Array using a pointer and a size_t. reading the documentation better next time ;) thank you.